# WooCommerce Cart Table Widths

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, cart

Just about given up trying to solve this! I should say though I am not great with code and there's probably an easy solution staring me in the face.

For some reason the column widths in my WooCommerce cart table are very off, the width of the 'product-remove' and 'product-thumbnail' columns is far too wide and I have no idea what is causing all the blank space to the right of the images?

I'd like the 'product-name' to be the only column with space to the right of the content if it doesn't fill the space.

[Have a play with the website here](https://www.raymondmayjewellers.com) and hopefully someone can come up with a solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

There is a rule in your CSS that's trying to make table TD's 50% wide:

```
.entry-content td {
    width: 50%;
}
```

Line 30 in the source code of the /cart/ page.

Comment: Editing it on the fly with inspect element that's definitely what I need to change, changing that to auto makes it display perfectly.

The issue now, is how do I go about changing that on a permanent basis?

Comment: Looking at the source code for the page, it looks like your theme inserts all the CSS code into the page, rather than into a separate style.css file. So I would start looking into the theme options, possibly the theme's header.php (but that's unlikely).

Alternatively, you could create an overriding css rule. The table's class is shop_table, so try:

   .entry-content .shop_table td { width: auto; }

Answer (score 0):

you can set width of columns by your self.

```
Plugins->editor->woocommerce->cart-template.php
```

can perform edit at this location like normal HTML. Its simple

Comment: I'd fiddled around in there a bit before and never managed to have any success, the problem is definitely coming from this 50% mentioned in the other answer, I just need to find where to edit that.